# relative path to images not working in CSS

Tags: html, css

My css file is in: `media` folder.
my images are in: `media/msg` folder.

[image]
This is the setting of the css file:

```
.info {
    color: #00529B;
    border-color: #789FCC;
    background-color: #CDEAF7;
    background-image: url('/msg/info.png');
}

.success {
    color: #264409;
    border-color: #C6D880;
    background-color: #E6EFC2;
    background-image:url('/msg/success.png');
}

.warning {
    color: #514721;
    border-color: #FFD324;
    background-color: #FFF6BF;
    background-image: url('/msg/warning.png');
}

.error {
    color: #8A1F11;
    border-color: #FBC2C4; 
    background-color: #FBE3E4;
    background-image: url('/msg/error.png');
```

The images are not loading.
When I do "inspect element" from browser it tells me "could not load the image".

as far as I know it should take the relative path of my css file and add the path to the image... but it doesn't work.

What do I do?

Comment: Remove the first "/", which cause the path to be absolute.

Comment: yes just remove the "/" from for eg. '/msg/error.png' to 'msg/error.png'

Comment: If your browser says "can't load image", what *absolute* url does it point to?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is because you are starting your paths with /...

```
'/msg/error.png' => base_url/msg/error.png
'msg/error.png' => css_url/msg/error.png
```

So just removing the / will work.

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS will be evaluated based on the file that imports it.

To avoid any issues, always give paths to images and other files based on the document root:

```
/media/msg/warning.png
```

Comment: @UnPeu You might need to clear your browser cache for the changes to your document to take place. (Or disable cache in developer tools.)

Comment: I do ctrl + f5 it's force refresh.. still didn't fix it.

Comment: Also, do you have any folders that are parents to the media folder? If so, you'll need to pre-pend every parent to the URL.