# HTML,CSS could not load from folders

Tags: php, html, css

So..
I have this code in my css

```
html {
    background: url("../img/bg.png") repeat fixed 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```

This is how my index.php includes css

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
```

My directory looks like this :

```
  ├ img
  | ├ bg.png
  ├ css
  | └ index.css
  └ fonts
  └ index.php
```

So.. my css is working because styling in it works on my webpage

But it could not load any images or anything that is loading from ../something

I'm using XAMPPs newest version so maybe it could be the reason..

Comment: Press F12 on your browser and have a look at what errors are logged in the console.

Comment: if you read this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609232/relative-path-to-images-not-working-in-css) and try what it says, does it help ?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers Failed to load resource, not found.. :(

Comment: From the console, get the image url, and try to open the image url in the browser to see if it loads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because of XAMPP so sorry for your time..

Answer (score 0):

try adding project / folder name, css loads but img in css doesn't load correct?

```
html {
    background: url("../foldername/img/bg.png" or "http://something/website/img/bg.png") repeat fixed 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
}
```